# Doubts about how to switch from implicit to parametric equations and vice versa. Linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

good afternoon.
I have several doubts about how to change from one type of equation to another, and vice versa.

Suppose I have the following system generated in vector space:

$$\left \langle \begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ 2\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ 5\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix}\right \rangle \subset \mathbb{R}^4$$

1. How can I obtain the parametric equations of the generator system?
2. And how do I make these parametric equations implicit?
3. Do they form a base? I think yes, because the rank of the matrix formed by the vectors of the generator system is maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already proved that the four vectors form a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ by looking at the rank of the corresponding matrix, you can say that a system of parametric equations is just:
$$\begin{cases} x_1 = a \\ x_2 = b \\ x_3 = c \\ x_4 = d \end{cases}$$
Indeed, the number of parameters is equal to the number of coordinates, because the subspace is equal to the whole space.
A system of Cartesian equations would then be the empty system, because it needs to be satisfied by the coordinates of any vector.

Now, *if you hadn't noticed this fact*, you could have proceeded as follows.

Let $v = \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4 \end{pmatrix}$ be a vector of the subspace. Then there exist $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$v = a \begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ 2\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ 5\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} + c \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
i.e., such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5a+b+c\\ 3b+2d\\ 2a+5b\\ 3a+b+3c+3d\end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore the parametric equations are:
$$\begin{cases} x_1 = 5a+b+c \\ x_2 = 3b+2d \\ x_3 = 2a+5b \\ x_4 = 3a+b+3c+3d \end{cases}.$$

In order to obtain the Cartesian equations, you need to solve the linear system above for $a, b, c, d$. You can write it in matrix form as:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, by applying Gaussian elimination to the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & x_1 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 & 2 & x_2 \\ 2 & 5 & 0 & 0  & x_3 \\ 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
you get
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 {94} (30 x_1 + 15 x_2 - 13 x_3 - 10 x_4) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 {47} (-6 x_1 - 3 x_2 + 12 x_3 + 2 x_4) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac 1 {94} (-44 x_1 - 69 x_2 + 41 x_3 + 46 x_4) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac 1 {47} (9 x_1 + 28 x_2 - 18 x_3 - 3 x_4) \end{pmatrix}$$
hence there are no Cartesian equations, because the row echelon form already has leading $1$'s in all rows.

For the sake of giving you an example, if you removed the fourth vector the matrix would become:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 1 & x_1 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 & x_2 \\ 2 & 5 & 0 & x_3 \\ 3 & 1 & 3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
which has row echelon form:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 6 (3 x_3 - 5 x_2) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac 1 2 x_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac 1 6 (6 x_1 + 23 x_2 - 15 x_3) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 x_1 + 56 x_2 - 36 x_3 - 6 x_4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then you would have a single Cartesian equation, namely
$$18 x_1 + 56 x_2 - 36 x_3 - 6 x_4 = 0.$$

Comment: And if the vectors don't form a basis. What I could to for obtaining it?

Comment: For example, here:  $$ < \begin{pmatrix}
5\\ 
4\\ 
3\\
1\\ 

\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\
2\\ 

\end{pmatrix}> \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$$

Comment: It's the same: for the parametric equations,
$$\begin{cases} x_1 = 5 a \\ x_2 = 4a + b \\ x_3 = 3a \\ x_4 = a + 2b \end{cases}$$
and then apply Gaussian elimination to the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 & x_1 \\ 4 & 1 & x_2 \\ 3 & 0 & x_3 \\ 1 & 2 & x_4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
The Cartesian equations are obtained by setting the third and fourth entry of the rightmost column to zero.

Comment: If have $18x+56y-36z-6t = 0$, how I could obtain a basis?